# Can't enable SSH on Catalina - System Preferences keeps saying "Remote Login starting..."

Tags: macos, catalina, ssh

I just did a complete reinstall of my late 2012 Mac Mini, with the latest OS it supports: Catalina (10.15.7). I'm trying to enable remote login via SSH, but when I check the box in System Preferences → Sharing, it keeps saying "Remote Login starting..." and I can't connect to it via SSH.

[image]

It looks like the same problem mentioned [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253932000). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem can be solved by manually adding the relevant launch daemon yourself via the Terminal, with the following command:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm. I'll just add that in order to disable the ssh daemon once again, it is necessary to execute the command `sudo launchctl **unload** -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`

Comment: Awesome. As soon as I ran the command in the terminal, the message "Remote Login starting..." changed to "Remote Login: On" with a green dot instead of yellow.

Comment: Is this solution supposed to also re-enable the functioning of the GUI (i.e. the Remote Login checkbox)? Or do we use it in place of the GUI? I have this problem - the launchctl commands do switch the GUI as @Tyler Collier describes, but I still can't get ssh login to work.